# Sending mail or SMS after the query has been executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, notifications

Currently I am dealing with a large dataset and some queries are executing several hours. In the meantime I am doing other things. In order to use time efficiently I have been thinking about implementing the logic to send email or SMS message after the query is complete so I can analyze the data.

I know how to do it by writing custom application but wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel if any similar solution already exists. Does anyone of you know if there already exists any notification system that could be used for this purpose?

Thank you

Comment: Kill two birds with one stone - send an email to your cell provider's SMS gateway? Implementation left as an exercise to the reader... :)

Comment: Inventing problems is not a good way to go when working on real projects - there could be thousand additional challenges found but time is too scarce;)

Comment: @David Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe there is no way to do that unless you create a client in high-level language

Comment: I haven't bothered to look into this, but could you potentially use SQLAgent or SSIS to send an email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) built in. You could run that as the last step of your batch.

Comment: +1.  That was where I was going when I asked about the platform, but I got sidetracked.  Good for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also execute the procedure from a job and use the notification email to send you an email. This would also give you the side benefit of having execution history.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/

And see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976651/sending-automated-sms-messages) about sending using regular ol' email to send SMS messages.